# The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'Boolean in Console Application

Tags: c#, wcf, ado.net, console-application

I am consuming wcf service into Console Application. I want to retrieve account information based on account number .when i enter the account number ,its able to method without any error but i got following errors in console application .

**: 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:AccountBalanceCheekResult. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Boolean. The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'Boolean'.'. Please see InnerException for more details.'**

Here is the class .

```
[DataContract]
    public class AccountBalanceRequest : Current_Account_Details
    {
        string account_number;

        [DataMember]
        public string Account_Number
        {
            get { return account_number; }
            set { account_number = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation  and i did not found any error in ADO.NET Code.

```
   public AccountBalanceRequest AccountBalanceCheek(AccountBalanceRequest accountNumber)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Current_Account_Details WHERE Account_Number = '" + accountNumber.Account_Number + "'", conn);


                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                //read the result of the execute command.
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //assuming that your property is the same as your table schema. refer to your table schema Current_Account_Details

                    accountNumber.Account_Number = reader["Account_Number"].ToString();
                    accountNumber.Account_Creation_Date = reader["Account_Creation_Date"].ToString();

                    accountNumber.Account_Type = reader["Account_Type"].ToString();
                    accountNumber.Branch_Sort_Code = reader["Branch_Sort_Code"].ToString();
                    accountNumber.Account_Fees = reader["Account_Fees"].ToString();
                    accountNumber.Account_Balance = reader["Account_Balance"].ToString();
                    accountNumber.Over_Draft_Limit = reader["Over_Draft_Limit"].ToString();
                }
                return accountNumber;
            }
        }
```

Here is the Console window code .

```
  public static void Balance()
        {
            MyService.HalifaxCurrentAccountServiceClient currentAccount = new MyService.HalifaxCurrentAccountServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IHalifaxCurrentAccountService");
            MyService.AccountBalanceRequest cs = new MyService.AccountBalanceRequest();


            string AccountNumber;


            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your Account Number--------:");
            AccountNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            cs.Account_Number = AccountNumber;
            // MyService.AccountBalanceRequest cs1 = currentAccount.AccountBalanceCheek(AccountNumber);



           if (currentAccount.AccountBalanceCheek(cs))**//Error on this line**
            {

                    Console.WriteLine("Your Account Number is :" + cs.Account_Number);
                    Console.WriteLine("Your Account Type :" + cs.Account_Balance);
                    Console.WriteLine("Your Account Account Fee :" + cs.Account_Fee);
                    Console.WriteLine("Your Account Balance:" + cs.Account_Balance);
                    Console.WriteLine("Your Account Over Draft Limit :" + cs.Over_Draft_Limit);

                    Console.Write("--------------------------");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    //Console.Clear();


           }

        }
```

Here is the screen shot when i run the application.

[click here to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noUZC.png)

Comment: This is a very fundamental question. The method you are calling does not return `bool` but you are checking as if it is returning a `bool`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you have the test

```
 if (currentAccount.AccountBalanceCheek(cs))
```

This assumes that the `AccountBalanceCheek()` function returns a bool, however the signature of the function suggests that it returns a `AccountBalanceRequest` type and not a boolean.

```
public AccountBalanceRequest AccountBalanceCheek(AccountBalanceRequest accountNumber)
```

You have a few options here, either adjust `AccountBalanceCheek` to returna  boolean value OR adjust the if function to have a comparison i.e

```
if(currentAccount.AccountBalanceCheek(cs) == someExpectedType)
```

Comment: What shall I enter someExpectedType??

Comment: That would be dependent on what you want to test for... right now your returning the object of type AccountBalanceRequest, so you could test if its null or not so you could do `!= null` or if you want to test a specific value within that class then do that.

Comment: As you can see in console code I want to display account details based on account number

Comment: Just change  `if (currentAccount.AccountBalanceCheek(cs))` to `if (currentAccount.AccountBalanceCheek(cs) != null)`

Answer (score 0):

There is one more additional way you can handle.

Since you are reading the account number from the console and if the reader object is able to figure out at least one record that means account with such number/id exists else account number doesnt exists.

```
    bool IsExist=false;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
    //into the loop means at least one record found so
    IsExist=true;
    accountNumber.Account_Number = reader["Account_Number"].ToString();
    }
return IsExist;
```

Also change the signature of the method from

```
public AccountBalanceRequest AccountBalanceCheek(AccountBalanceRequest accountNumber)
```

to

```
public bool AccountBalanceCheek(AccountBalanceRequest accountNumber)
```